# Issue With Managed Package?

Tags: community

I have Created a lookup Relation ship between Registration Custom object  to Opportunity object and i have written some apex classes on these two objects.I have added these components to Managed package .

When i am trying to install managed package in Force.com platform it is throughing error Bcz The opportunity object is not available in force.com edition...

Can any one please help on this

Answer (score 1):

Opportunity is a standard object and doesn't available under Force.com license. You can't avoid it with this licence's type.